# How do I add tabGroup to SplitWindow in Titanium for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, titanium, titanium-mobile

Currently, I am building an application for the iPad with titanium. I want to add a tabGroup to a splitWindow, But I just can't seem to get it working. The tabs never show, and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

I am using the dummy code from the [docs](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.iPad.SplitWindow-object.html):

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var nav = Ti.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
   window: win
});

var masterView = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var tabwin = Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor: '#FFF'});

var tabs = Ti.UI.createTabGroup();

var tab = Ti.UI.createTab({
    window: tabwin,
    title: 'Tab'
});

tabs.addTab(tab);
masterView.add(tabs);
tabs.show();

var splitwin = Ti.UI.iPad.createSplitWindow({
    detailView:nav,
    masterView:masterView
});

splitwin.addEventListener('visible',function(e)
{
    if (e.view == 'detail')
    {
        e.button.title = "Master";
        win.leftNavButton = e.button;
    }
    else if (e.view == 'master')
    {
        win.leftNavButton = null;
    }
});

var tabwindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: 'Master',
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    navBarHidden: false
});


splitwin.open();
```

The `masterView` i changed to a tabGroup (which doesn't show a thing anymore after I run it in simulator. When I try to add a tabGroup to the MasterView, the splitscreen does show the window, but doesn't show the tabGroup.

My question now is, how do I add tabs or a tabgroup to the SplitWindow?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan as noted below the code, I changed it to a tabgroup, or a window with a added TabGroup, but I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Can't you use a tabgroup with a split window instead of splitwindow with a tabgroup?

Comment: SplitWindow is top level only..

Comment: Do you want to show the tab in master view only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this in your code:

> tabs.open();

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it and come back to you

Comment: didn't really work. I changed to code in the question again. And indeed, I only want tabs in the sidebar/master

Comment: *banging head against the wall*. Thanks